# ax+by+cz<=d, find the maximum value of ax+by+cz.

Tags: inequality, integer-programming

I am recently calculating that kind of questions as shown in title.

And of course, I use a lot of time to find the answer. Therefore I would

like to know how I can calculate faster.

Q.: *ax* + *by* + *cz* <= *d*, find the maximum value of *ax* + *by* + *cz*.

(*a*, *b*, *c*, *d*, *x*, *y* and *z* are non-negative integers.)

E.g.1: 1529 *x* + 1911 *y* + 2294 *z* <= 5733 ; A.: 5733 (*x*=0, *y*=3, *z*=0).

E.g.2: 1529 *x* + 1911 *y* + 2294 *z* <= 5734 ; A.: 5734 (*x*=1, *y*=1, *z*=1).

Method used to find the answers: substitution.

Please help me, 'cos I am stuck and there are

more and more unknowns later on. Thank you!

Comment: If this is for a class, have you learned any techniques for this sort of thing? If it's not for a class, write a computer program to find the solutions?

Comment: I wrote a clumsy substitution program. but i have no idea how to calculate the answer step-by-step.

Comment: It seems that you are supposing that $a,b,c,d,x,y,z$ are all non-negative integers. Am I wrong? (otherwise the maximum is always $d$ ).

Comment: @Crostul, you are right. I forgot to write that down.

Comment: Related is http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27884/non-negative-integer-solutions-of-a-single-linear-diophantine-equation